# Unable to save information to database and blank page appears when clicked on submit button

Tags: php, mysql

Upon clicking on the signup button , the page gets blank and information not stored on the database. The following is my code

```
<?php


{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


if(isset($_POST['signup'])){

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];




    if($firstname ==''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
    exit();
    }


$query = "insert into users(firstname) VALUES ($firstname) ";
$query = $conn->prepare($query);
$query->bindParam('1', $firstname);

$query->execute();
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: `{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}` is not a right way of writing code.

Comment: sorry sir..this is the full code

// PDO connect
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ecomm";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

Comment: try to add html code also.

Comment: here you go sir ..   <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
  <form id='signup_form' action='register.php' method="POST">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control">
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <input style="width:100%;" value="Sign Up" type="submit" name="signup"class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
       </div>
      </div>
      
     </div>
 
</body>
</form>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to bind parameter with query properly.

If you are using PDO then use this to bind the firstname

```
$query = "insert into users(firstname) VALUES (:firstname)";
$query = $conn->prepare($query);
$query->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$query->execute();
```

OR

If you are using Mysqli then

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into users(firstname) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$firstname);
$stmt->execute();
```